# how to display a template.php in a shortcode

Tags: plugins, themes, shortcode, templates

I have created a template in WordPress page-example.php, which has HTML, javascript, php

I would like to use that template in a shorcode

Any way to do it?
I have this code but it doesn't work for me:

```
function jb_shortcode_de_contenido() {
$handler = curl_init("https://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/page-vcardweb.php");  
$response = curl_exec ($handler);  
curl_close($handler);  
echo $response; 
 }
```

Comment: [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it? But if it really is a theme template, it might rely on WP magic (the loop, global variables, specific state, ..) that is not available from within your Shortcode.

Comment: is this template on the same site? Shortcodes do not echo their content, they return it. If you `echo` or output directly in a shortcode it will break lots of things, e.g. nested shortcodes, the order it appears, REST API endpoints used by the editor, AJAX responses etc. Also, loading that PHP file doesn't mean the posts that page template displays will be shown.